# how to get the first item selected on loading the listbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

i have this listbox loading items from database now i need the first item to stay selected on loading it, please help. I tried in jquery but that din't help.

```
@model  proj.Models.ListboxViewModel
@Html.ListBoxFor( m=> m.resourcename,Model.resourcename, new { @class = "resList",style="height: 121px;"})

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("select[name='resourcename']").removeAttr('multiple');
        $("select[name='resourcename']").attr('size', '8');
     //   $("#resourcename").find("option").attr("selected", '1'); // this is not working
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You can create a ListItem Collection and mark whichever item you want as Selected = true

Comment: @Nilesh Thankyou for responding : ) . can you please be a little more brief?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite quickly in JQuery

JQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("select[name='resourcename']").find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

To get the value of the the select box using jquery try.

```
function getValue() {
    var resid = $("select[name='resourcename']").val();
    alert(resid)
}
```

Cheers

Comment: How to get resid from this?
var resid = document.getElementById('resourcename').options.selectedIndex.value;
                alert(resid);

Comment: Is this a new question? I will edit my answer to show the value.

Comment: I added the script to select the first item but now i'm getting alert as undefined when i added the function .

Comment: Can you open a new question for this with your full code so I can see the implementation?

Comment: Thankyou Nico :) Please note this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893277/selected-listbox-item-as-undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Jquery function `.prop()`, is the safest way to do it:

```
$("select[name='resourcename']").find("option:first").prop('selected',true);
```