# Selected listbox item as undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox, selecteditem

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("select[name='CusList']").removeAttr('multiple');
        $("select[name='CusList']").attr('size', '8');
        $("select[name='CusList']").find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
        //fx();
    });

    function fx() {
        var resid = $("select[name='resourcename']").val();
        alert(resid);            
    }
</script>

@Html.ListBox("CusList", ((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Customer"]), new { @class = "k-list"})
```

I tried to call `fx()` from the pageload(on controller) and also inside the function().
Both alert as `undefined`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready (function(){
        $('#CusList').bind("click", function () {
            debugger;
            var resid = document.getElementById('CusList');
            var id = resid.options[resid.selectedIndex].value;
            alert(id); //this gives me id correcly, so ly listbox is correct for sure
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In the `fx()` function you're looking for a `select` named `resourcename`, yet your C# code is creating one called `CusList`.

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("select[name='CusList']")
        .removeAttr('multiple')
        .attr('size', '8')
        .find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
    fx();
});

function fx() {
    var resid = $("select[name='CusList']").val();
    alert(resid);            
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I was using two sample codes, 
is there anyother way to achieve the listbox selected item instead of using bind?